# Setting west, east, north, south to position with tikzmark

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikzmark

I'm using the library `tikzmark` with `usetikzlibrary(tikzmark)`.

The following code

```
\newcommand{\DrawCircle}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[color=red] (pic cs:#1) circle (0.25cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

works, but this code

```
\newcommand{\DrawHLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[shorten <=0.2em, #1] (pic cs:#2.west) -- (pic cs:#3.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

wont draw the line correctly due to the `.west` and `.east`. If I remove these, the line is drawn. How can I use `.west`, `.east`, `.north`, and `.south` properly with `tikzmark`?

Comment: Please provide a full example so that we can copy-paste-compile the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tikzmark` creates *coordinates* and coordinates do not have distinct anchors because they are points. So `coordinate.west` would be just the same as `coordinate.east` and there's no point defining them.

[Drawing on [percusse's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235632/setting-west-east-north-south-to-position-with-tikzmark/235638?noredirect=1#comment558852_235638), they are all equivalent to `coordinate.center` which is just the same as `coordinate`.]

Comment: Coordinates are also node shapes and they only have one anchor which is `center`. Everything else is mapped to  `center`.

Answer (score 6):

As an extension to cfr's answer, you can define your own `\tikzmark`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline]\node [anchor=base] (#1) {#2};
}
\newcommand{\DrawHLine}[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[shorten <=0.2em, #1] (#2.west) -- (#3.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
  \tikzmark{a}{Some text in tikzmark}

  \mbox{}\hfill
  \tikzmark{b}{Some text in another tikzmark}
  \DrawHLine{b}{a}
\end{document}
```

Here `\node` is used instead of `\coordinate` to make `east` `west` etc anchors available. If you are loading `tikzmark` library, don't forget to give a different name to the macro.

[image]

Comment: (+1) Though it would be easier if we knew how `\tikzmark` was being used!

Comment: Thank you! I will use this tikzmark command instead. It would just be easier if I could use the in-built function I think.

Comment: I've now used your suggestion and it looks fine. But if I use `\tikzmark{topA}{-1}` in a matrix `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}` it seems that $-1$ will be interpreted as text instead of a math number. It's obvious that the formatting is different when I have multiple $-1$ values in my matrix. I've also tried `\tikzmark{topA} -1` but I guess it's making the cell a 'text cell' if I'm using `\tikzmark`.

Comment: @Jamgreen Use `\tikzmark{topA}{$-1$}` or if you have many of them, change the definition of `\tikzmark` as `\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline]\node [anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};` i.e., enclose `#2` inside `$`.

Answer (score 4):

cfr's answer is not quite correct, though it is close enough for practical purposes.  It is true that `tikzmark` does not create a node, but neither does it create a coordinate.  It doesn't create anything, it does almost the bare minimum needed to mark a point on the page and no more (not *quite* the bare minimum, there's `\pgfmark` which is the absolute bare minimum).  The point of not making a coordinate or node is that then the position is available *before* the `\tikzmark` is issued as well as afterwards (nodes and coordinates would only be available afterwards).

The original `\tikzmark` was quite like Harish's version, but it was modified (in response to a question here, I think) to the current version to allow for the above situation.  Nevertheless, to provide the same functionality as the original, `\tikzmark` can take an optional first argument which can be any TikZ code.

Thus `\tikzmark[{\node[anchor=base] {\(-1\)}}]{a}` will produce a `node` inside the `\tikzmark`.
(Moreover, the name of the `tikzmark` is passed without "protection" so it can be co-opted to pass further options to the `\tikz` command as in `\tikzmark[stuff]{a,baseline=0pt}`.)  This isn't quite the same as Harish's version, but to know what to put into the `tikzmark` arguments I'd need to know exactly what you were trying to do.

However, the philosophy of `tikzmark` is that it solves the basic problem, but not *every* problem.  If you want to do something complicated then you're better off making a proper tikzpicture or your own macro (as Harish suggests).  The number of possibilities for `tikzmark` are so large that anticipating every single one is more than I can manage.  So while you can co-opt the in-built `\tikzmark` to do what you want, defining a new macro is the "LaTeX way".  After all, `\tikzmark` began life that way.

Comment: Good ol' times :)